# UITableView with static cell - different separation color per section?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have UITableView with static cells in 4 sections done in Storyboard. However, I want to change the separator color for one section ([UIColor clearColor]). How can I do that??? Is it actually possible?

I can set the separatorColor to clearColor for the entire table, but not only for one specific section.

Screenshot of table view section:

[image: Screenshot of table view section]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no method for this. But you can put a background image to the cell which has a separator at the bottom and set separatorstyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone. So you have your own separator in every cell.

Comment: I have asked on iphonesdk.com forum and Manish915 replied me this and even attached a screenshot of it so I guess it should not be that difficult http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/106224-uitablewiew-with-static-cell-different-separation-color-per-section.html

Comment: I am not sure but you can try. Anyway your cellForRowAtIndexPath method should start like this: 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (! cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve your goal by setting the header text for the section to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would to create your own `UIView` subclass and do your own custom drawing in `drawRect:`.  You would take this view and add it as the `backgroundView` of your table view cell.  Something like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    // Draw black line
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3};
    CGColorRef blackColor = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, blackColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, rect.size.height - 1.5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 1.5);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorRelease(blackColor);

    // Draw white bottom line
    CGFloat whiteComponents[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75f};
    CGColorRef whiteColor = CGColorCreate(colorspace, whiteComponents);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, whiteColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, rect.size.height - 0.5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 0.5);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorRelease(whiteColor);

    // Draw top white line
    CGFloat whiteTransparentComponents[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.45};
    CGColorRef whiteTransparentColor = CGColorCreate(colorspace, whiteTransparentComponents);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, whiteTransparentColor);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0.5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rect.size.width, 0.5);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorRelease(whiteTransparentColor);



    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
}
```